Is it possible to do a constructor autowire of a generic bean with several implementations in Spring boot?
In my current project we have one service with common preprocessing logic that does work on generic entities before passing them on to their target service, now the current implementation is misusing generics and creating several code quality warnings in SonarQube, so I'm trying to refactor it to use generics properly if possible. I'm facing an issue now where Spring is unable to create the main class because of multiple beans fulfilling the requirement.
I got to this point so far:
public class IceCreamService implements OrderService<IcecreamOrder, IcecreamOrderDto> { ... }
public class BurgerService implements OrderService<BurgerOrder, BurgerOrderDto> { ... }
public class PizzaService implements OrderService<PizzaOrder, PizzaOrderDto> { ... }

Where the generic parameters extend a base Order and OrderDto class respectively, and OrderService is an interface that defines the signature of all supported methods.
Then we have a generic class of the form:
public class OrderOperation<T extends Order, U extends OrderDto> {
    private final OrderService<T, U> targetService;
    ...
}

This OrderOperation class is what's autowired to all controllers that do work on Order and OrderDto classes.
Now the roadblock I've hit is that Spring complains that multiple beans exist that satisfy the dependency when trying to autowire OrderOperation.
I tried setting @Scope(value = "prototype") but it didn't really work.
What should I try here? I've considered reversing the order of operations from generic service -> target service to target service -> generic service but it would require a major change in the code base, so if possible this current structure would be best to keep.

I had to change my approach for this, the way I ended up solving it was by autowiring the list of services implementing the interface and manually creating an entity-service map, then changing the methods to fit the new signature. It looks something like this now:
public class OrderOperation<T extends Order, U extends OrderDto> {
    private final List<OrderService<T, U>> orderServices;
    private final Map<Class<T>, OrderService<T, U>> serviceMap = new HashMap();

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        orderServices.forEach(service -> serviceMap.put(service.getEntityType(), service));
    }

    private OrderService<T, U> getService(Class<T> entityType) {
        Optional.ofNullable(orderServices.get(entityType)).orElseThrow();
    ...
}

Methods that depend on another service will call getService to get an instance. Not the way I originally wanted to fix it but closest I could get.
